# How to write two lines to one line?

Tags: author

[image]

Yellow box is my affiliation's name.

It's so long that it occupies two lines.

I want to make this into a single line.

What should I do?

```
\author{name name}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institute of Science and Technology}
  \city{city city}
  \country{country country}}
\email{mail mail}
```

Comment: This mostly depends on the document class you’re using. Please, tell us some more details.

Comment: @egreg you mean, this?  \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}.
This is a document for the conference paper ACM, and the image above is about the author name and affiliations.  From this https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template

Comment: Since it's supposed to be centered, you could add some negative space on each side: `\institution{\hspace*{-2em}...\hspace{-2em}}`.  This may have unexpected side effects when the paper is processed by the publisher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\mbox{}` or `\nolinebreak`. Afaik, `\verbatim` also prevents linebreaks. Provide a MWE so we can demonstrate the effects.